# value Error in linear regression predict: "ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (132,132) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 132 (dim 0)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

i am new in machine learning and linear regression can some one help me to fix this issue of value error

**"ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (132,132) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 132 (dim 0)"**

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Laod the data
load_csv = pd.read_csv("Gdp_Vs_Life_Dataset.csv")
gdp = np.c_[load_csv["GDP"]]
life = np.c_[load_csv["LIFE"]]

print (load_csv.shape)
print (gdp)
print (life)
print(gdp.size)
print(life.size)

# Visualize the data
plt.scatter(gdp,life)
plt.xlabel('GDP PER CAPITA')
plt.ylabel('LIFE SATISFACTION')
plt.title("Data year 2016")
plt.show()

# Select a linear model
model = LinearRegression()

#Train the model
model.fit(gdp.reshape(1, -1), life.reshape(1, -1))

# Make a prediction
X_ = [[5989]]
print(model.predict(X_))
```

When i run this code i got an error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "linear_reg.py", line 33, in 
    print(model.predict(X_))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 200, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 185, in _decision_function
    dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 184, in safe_sparse_dot
    return fast_dot(a, b)
ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (132,132) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 132 (dim 0)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your the feature dimension input `X_` should be `132`; right now, it's `1` (a scalar).

Comment: But i am looking for predict life satisfaction based on single GDP input. can you just help me to some briefly explanation on this how can i predict life satisfaction by given single input 'X_'?

Answer (score 0):

Me too, I got same error.

But using

```
reg.predict(np.array([[5989]]))
```

instead of first assigning

```
X_ = [[5989]]
print(model.predict(X_))
```

So use directly:

```
reg.predict(np.array([[5989]]))
```

and the issue is solved.